# React Native - onPress function does not trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to create a button that shows a message on an alert box using the following code:

```
buttonClicked= () => {return alert("clicked")}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.buttonClicked()} style={styles.skip}>
 <Text>Skip</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

However, clicking "Skip" text does not trigger the `buttonClicked` function. The only way I was able to trigger the function was when I removed the arrow function from the onPress class.
`onPress={this.buttonClicked()}`
But, that results in function to be only triggered when the app first starts.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

All parts of the code expect App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'

export default class Tutorials extends Component {
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state={
            currentPage: 1,
            totalPages: 3,
        }
    }

    setCurrentPage = () => {return alert("clicked")}

    renderTutorial = () =>{
        if(this.state.currentPage === 1)
        {
            return(
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Image style={styles.arrow} source={require('../../assets/path.png')}/>
                    <Text style={styles.pages}>{this.state.currentPage + ' of ' + this.state.totalPages}</Text>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setCurrentPage()} style={styles.skip}>
                        <Text>Skip</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>


                    <Text style={styles.header}>Refer to friend</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Your friend will also receive credits</Text>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.inviteFriendsButton} onPress={()=>alert("clicked!")}>
                        <Image source={require('../../assets/buttonInviteFriends.png')}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            );
        }
        if(this.state.currentPage === 2)
        {
            <View>Page 2</View>
        }
        if(this.state.currentPage === 3)
        {
            <View>Page 3</View>
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            this.renderTutorial()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557745/difference-in-passing-callbacks-into-react-component/60557771#60557771

Comment: @keikai Unfortunately, no.

Comment: provide some more details like is it a functional component or a class component . If possible share the complete code for component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `absolute` positioning changing that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onPress={this.buttonClicked}
```

Comment: Similar to the arrow function, still does not trigger the function

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code in the following way:

```
buttonClicked = () => alert("clicked")

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.buttonClicked} style={styles.skip}>
 <Text>Skip</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Or for testing purposes plugging it directly into the `onPress`:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("clicked")} style={styles.skip}>
 <Text>Skip</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: A lot of answers in this feed really are supposed to work. Are you sure that you are referencing your function properly? Can you get a proper output if you `console.log(this.buttonClicked)`?

Comment: I agree but I dont know why it doesnt work. Even onPress={()=>console.log("click")} doesnt work

Comment: If that doesn't work then you have to make sure that it is this touchable object that you are trying to access and press. If that doesn't work, that means you could be pressing something else

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should change the function you are triggering via the ***onPress*** prop to

```
buttonClicked() {
    return alert("clicked")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.buttonClicked} style={styles.skip}>
   <Text>Skip</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Hope it will be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

See below example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  buttonClicked = () => {
    return alert('clicked');
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.buttonClicked}  
          style={styles.skip}>
          <Text>Skip</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>    
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  skip: {
    width: '90%',
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
};

export default App;
```

Feel free for doubts.